# Show element having child element with specific CSS class

Tags: jquery

I have 2 hidden DIVs

every DIV contains a SPAN

I want to show only the DIV who has the SPAN with class RedBackground

The javascript code i wrote is not working

```js
$("div span.RedBackground").show();
```

```css
.greenBackground {
    color: green;
}

.RedBackground {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display: none;">
<span  class="RedBackground">show this</span>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
<span  class="GreenBackground">NOT show this</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:has` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to get all `div` containing such element. Not need to use things like `parent` or `closest`:

```js
$("div:has(span.RedBackground)").show();
```

```css
.greenBackground { color: green; }
.RedBackground { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display: none;">
  <span  class="RedBackground">show this</span>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
  <span  class="GreenBackground">NOT show this</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Selector is the other way around.
2. use `$("span.RedBackground").parent('div')` to show div. means `span.RedBackground`'s parent div which is hidden is shown
3. your selector `$("div span.RedBackground").show();` means  div with `span.RedBackground` but the div is hidden so you cant still see any
4. Commented below if there are other element between the span and the hidden div you can use `closest("div")`

```js
$("span.RedBackground").parent('div').show();
```

```css
.greenBackground {
    color: green;
}

.RedBackground {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display: none;">
<span  class="RedBackground">show this</span>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
<span  class="GreenBackground">NOT show this</span>
</div>
```

Comment: eventually you can replace parent() with closest() just in case there is something else between <div> and <span>.